# Missing surefire-reports in jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

When running `mvn test` I see following on console -

`[INFO] Surefire report directory: /mnt/vdb/jenkins/jobs/selenium-production-tests/workspace/target/surefire-reports`

But when I print directories in `target` dir then I get -

```
Directory classes
Directory surefire
Directory maven-status
Directory test-classes
Directory generated-sources
Directory generated-test-sources
```

Why is `surefire-reports` missing in here?

I am printing directories as -

```
        File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
            if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFile.getName());
            } else if (listOfFile.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFile.getName());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `basedir` instead of `user.dir` apart from that why are you trying to access via file? running a kind of integration tests based on reading something about selenium? If so maven-surefire-plugin is the wrong cause integration tests should be run by maven-failsafe-plugin..naming schema: unit test `*Test.java` while integration tests `*IT.java` see docs of maven-failsafe/maven-surefire plugin...

Comment: I want to get to `/target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml` file. Using `basedir` also does not show `surefire-reports` under `target` folder. In fact I get the same result as when I use `user.dir`. Where is `surefire-reports` directory hidden?

Comment: First you should use `basedir` and add the appropriate directory to it...`basedir` is located in the directory where `pom.xml` is located. But to be honest I don't know why you are trying to find those directories, cause unit test results are accumulated by Jenkins ...So I don't understand your approach or better what you like to achieve and what kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My bad. `Delete workspace before build starts` was checked hence workspace was deleted each time I built and hence `surefire-report` folder was missing.